# Change npm build destination folder to tomcat

Tags: javascript, node.js, tomcat, npm, parcel

I am making an app and for this I am using multiple Open Source applications. Now I have a question about NPM and Tomcat.

(Some background info: I have a workspace with two maps: 1. Project (with NODE.JS, NPM, PARCEL and the .html and .js for the app) 2. Tomcat (with geoserver.)

At the moment my app is shown by Tomcat and this is how:

1. I make my app in JavaScript and then I do a 'npm run build' in my projectfolder. This creates a few files in the project /dist map.
2. I copy those files an put them in a /dist folder I made in the Tomcat /webapps folder.
3. The application is show.

The problem with this? Every time I change my code I have to run a build manually and copy the files from the project folder tot the tomcat webapps folder. This is not a a good solution as you can understand.

My question:
**Can I change the destination for the files made by 'npm run build' and then maybe also for 'npm start'? As I understand it the npm start makes sure that all the changes that are made in the JavaScript are automatically updated.**

I need this because I get input from my end-user via the web browser. This input determines which date is shown by my application.

I have never worked with NPM before, so maybe it is a bit of a dumb question. But I can't find the answer myself. So I hope someone can help!

EDIT: contents of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Weather",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
  },
  "author": "T",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "ol": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.10.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of your package.json? that is where the `start` command that npm runs is defined

Comment: I added the code to the original post!